# Get the auto-generated ID after an insert

Tags: php, database, insert, oracle10g, primary-key

I have an Oracle Express 10g database. In my table I have an auto-generated ID and I would like to know how I can find what the generated ID is after an insert happens. I am currently using PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the returning id into a variable. For example, this code:

```
$data = array("larry","bill","steve");
$db = OCILogon("scott","tiger");
$stmt = OCIParse($db,"insert into names values (myid.nextval,:name) returning id into :id");

OCIBindByName($stmt,":ID",$id,32);
OCIBindByName($stmt,":NAME",$name,32);

while (list(,$name) = each($data))
{
     OCIExecute($stmt);
     echo "$name got id:$id\n"; 
}
```

This gives you the ID got by `$name` in form of the variable `$id`. Change your SQL accordingly.

Comment: i tried and it work in part becouse for each insert jump a value, the "myid.nextval" can by deleted to use all the possible key.

tnks

Comment: You're welcome. This was just a demo. You need to customize the code yourself.