# using codeigniter and need to get id of last auto-incremented id for next query, using oci8

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oracle-call-interface

Using codeigniter and oci8 for a project.

$this->db->insert_id(); would would perfect for getting the last auto-incremented id of the previous query, but it does not seem to work on an oracle database.

Any help is appreciated. I would LOVE to use mysql, but an oracle database is a requirement.

$this->db->insert_id(); for codeigniter, is just like php's mysql_insert_id()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

[Get the auto-generated ID after an insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558433)

```
$data = array("value1","value2","value3");
$db = OCILogon("user","password");
$stmt = OCIParse($db,"insert into mytable values (myid.nextval,:myfield) returning id into :id");

OCIBindByName($stmt,":ID",$id,32);
OCIBindByName($stmt,":MYFIELD",$myfield,32);

while (list(,$myfield) = each($data)) {
OCIExecute($stmt);
 echo "$myfieldgot id:$id\n";
}
```

You could also look at using a DB interface layer like [PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Comment: Thanks Ergo, this helped me find http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/123884/#613503, which may do the trick.

Comment: No probs, let us know if it works so it may help others in future :)

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the next sequence number?

SELECT ' || cTableName || '_seq.currval from dual

?

Comment: Say I have tables comments(id, message), transactions(comment_id, step_id), steps(id, title) - the steps table is pre-defined, when the user submits form, it will add it to the comments table, and it will refer to one of the steps, so I need to store into comments table, then grab newly generated comments.id and store it into transactions table, w/ the appropriate step_id too.

Comment: so it would be INSERT INTO comments (message) VALUES ('this is my msg') - then I need to store comments.id of that newly created id into $comment_id = comments.id from query just ran, then run a query INSERT INTO transactions ('comment_id', 'step_id') VALUES ($comment_id, $step_id) - unsure how/where _seq.currval should go in all that.

Comment: look here:  http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/Getting-the-last-inserted-sequence-value for how they implemented it.  I don't know if you have this level of access.