# how i can get inserted id by php and oracle

Tags: php, oracle

i know that its not first time someone ask this question, i look at questions in stakoverflow which covered same subject but they didnt give me what i need, my request is how can get inserted id by php and oracle i have table named USERS with 3 columns ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD so i neeed the inserted primary id

i know how make that by php + mysql

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS(USERNAME,PASSWORD)VALUES('{JOHN}','{1235}')");
if(!$insert){
die(mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_inserted_id();
```

please help me to do it in oracle i want do it with out use OCIBindByName

Comment: read this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558433/php-oracle-take-the-autogenerated-id-after-an-insert

Comment: i dont use ocilogon and dont love to use `OCIBindByName($stmt,":ID",$id,32);
OCIBindByName($stmt,":NAME",$name,32);`
it make me confusing i need to apply that like example which i make

Comment: There are two good reasons to ALWAYS use bind variables: security and performance. It is a little shortsighted to not use bind variables just because you think they are "confusing".

Answer (score 1):

OCILogon is a synonym for oci_connect. Please read manual first before saying "I don't use this" ;)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ocilogon.php

So the solution is here:
[Get the auto-generated ID after an insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558433/php-oracle-take-the-autogenerated-id-after-an-insert)

And I don't see why not to use OCIBindByName. There is nothing to love ;) Just use what's effective and easy.

Comment: @user700792 Why "without"? What are your reasons?

Comment: oky could you learn me how to do it without OCIBindByName cuz i dont understand OCIBindByName and it make me confusing....please please help me to make it without OCIBindByName

Answer (score -1):

Do you have think to use a Trigger "Before insert" on Oracle TABLE USERS and an Oracle Sequence to generate a unique number?
[Oracle Trigger Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) and [Use of Oracle Sequences](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sequences.htm)

I think this a possible solution.

Bye