# Error : This feature is not available for the database you are using when trying to return insert_id

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I have function in my codeigniter model returning the function insert_id()
I am using Oracle11g, Does anyone know how to return the last inserted record in codeigniter using Oracle DB
Here is an example of what I will like to do

```
public function test_insert($data)
{
  $this->db->insert('PERFORMANCE', $data);
      return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Your help will be well appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this the insert_id() feature is not available for Oracle11g.
You can refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558433/get-the-auto-generated-id-after-an-insert), for the alternative.