# Get auto generated id from Oracle after insert using php DB class

Tags: php, oracle, class, oop, model

So I have a spaghetti PHP app I am converting to using OOP database class / MVC layout

Previously, on a form, there was a sql statement being executed on post that would fetch the inserted ID into a bind variable (based on the SO [Get the auto-generated ID after an insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558433/get-the-auto-generated-id-after-an-insert)

```
$sql ="insert into table (name, type) values (:name, :type) returning id into :id";
$squery = oci_parse($link, $sql);
  oci_bind_by_name($squery,":name", $_POST['name']);  
  oci_bind_by_name($squery,":type", $_POST['type']);
  oci_bind_by_name($squery,":id", $id,-1, SQLT_INT);
oci_execute($squery);
```

at this point, $id could be used as the variable has been assigned the inserted id

So, here is my issue, my model passes the values from the $_POST to the database class, but never assigns the variable

Model

```
function create(){

$sql ="insert into table (name, type) values (:name, :type) returning id into :id";
 $this->db->execute($sql, "table insert", 
 array(
   array(":name", $_POST['name'], -1, SQLT_CHR),
   array(":type", $_POST['type'], -1, SQLT_CHR),
   array(":id", $id,-1, SQLT_INT)
        )
    );
 return $id;
}
```

Database Class( based on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_three_db_access_class.htm )

```
public function execute($sql, $action, $bindvars = array()) {
    $this->stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
    if ($this->prefetch >= 0) {
        oci_set_prefetch($this->stid, $this->prefetch);
    }
    foreach ($bindvars as $bv) {
        // oci_bind_by_name(resource, bv_name, php_variable, length , type)
        oci_bind_by_name($this->stid, $bv[0], $bv[1], $bv[2], $bv[3]);
    }
    oci_set_action($this->conn, $action);
    oci_execute($this->stid);              // will auto commit

}
```

The class is correct, meaning it will execute fine , it just will not return the last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i came up with (surely theres a better answer)

the issue was when i passed in the variable for returning into bind, it was not passing the variable as a variable ($id) it was passing it in as a variable value, and it hadnt been assigned so it was blank

so in my database class i created

```
public function executeAndReturnID($sql, $action, $bindvars = array(), $return) {
    $this->stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
    if ($this->prefetch >= 0) {
        oci_set_prefetch($this->stid, $this->prefetch);
    }
    foreach ($bindvars as $bv) {

        oci_bind_by_name($this->stid, $bv[0], $bv[1], $bv[2], $bv[3]);
    }
    // THIS PART TAKES THE RETURN AND CREATES A BIND AND VARIABLE
    oci_bind_by_name($this->stid, ':'.$return, $res, -1, SQLT_INT);

    oci_execute($this->stid);              // will auto commit
    $this->stid = null;  // free the statement resource
    return($res);   

    }
```

and in my Model

```
function create(){

$sql ="insert into table (name, type) values (:name, :type) returning id into :id";
 $id = $this->db->executeAndReturnID($sql, "table insert", 
 array(
   array(":name", $_POST['name'], -1, SQLT_CHR),
   array(":type", $_POST['type'], -1, SQLT_CHR),

        ),
   "id" //the bind var for return into
    );
 return $id;
}
```